# What is the difference between output_buffering vs ob_start?

Tags: php

Trying to understand the difference between using "output_buffering = on" in .user.ini and the ob_start function directly in a script?

Does one give me more control over the other in terms of limiting the buffer size, or when the buffer is published to the browser?

Comment: Inifile sets the default for all files while with `ob_start` you can select when and where you want to start. Apart from that there doesn't seem to be much difference, functionally.

Comment: Thank you for your help!